# Binding a control

Tags: wpf, binding, controls

I created my control in code and I want to bind this control to XAML.
How I can do that?
(I need help only in preparing XAML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ContentControl to host your usercontrol.

```
  <ContentControl   Content="{Binding ........}"/>
```

I am not sure this is want you want. I hope this help.